# Prove: $f(x)=0, \forall x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ if $|f'(x)|\le |f(x)$ and $f(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f:[0,\frac{1}{2}] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $|f^\ {'}(x)|\leq |f(x)|$ and $f(0)=0.$  Prove: $f(x)=0, \forall x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

So I tried to work by the definition of the derivative at $0$ and somehow squeeze it, but got stuck.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052785/consequence-of-mean-value-theorem, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509876/prove-fx-0-for-all-x-in-0-infty-when-fx-leq-fx, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816021/prove-that-fx-equiv0-on-left0-1-right

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383413/condition-to-guarantee-f-0-on-a-b.